# Finding memory breakpoints from debugged executable

Tags: windows, ollydbg, anti-debugging, protection

Is it possible to find `Memory Breakpoints` from within the debugged executable? (as an anti debugging technique?). And no, i **do not mean** `Hardware Breakpoints` from the `Dr0 - Dr7` registers **NOR** `INT3 \ code breakpoints`.. Breakpoints like in OllyDBG when you right click a memory address and put a breakpoint on access.

What ways exist to find such breakpoints?
How can i avoid detection?

Answer (score 2):

You could query the page level attributes of the section you're trying to verify. If the attributes contain unexpected values (e.g. *PAGE_NOACCESS*), chances are that someone messed with your pages (possibly a debugger setting a memory breakpoint).

Comment: Can u give me real life examples of how its done? Are there any alternatives to `VirtualProtectEx` and `VirtualQueryEx`?

Comment: The only alternative I can think of would be [NtQueryVirtualMemory](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/source/usermode/undocumented%20functions/memory%20management/virtual%20memory/ntqueryvirtualmemory.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in-depth in this blog post: http://waleedassar.blogspot.com/2012/11/defeating-memory-breakpoints.html

> ... This trick can easily detect memory breakpoints. It relies on the fact
>   that the "**ReadProcessMemory**" function returns false if you try to read
>   guarded or no-access memory. To use this trick, all you have to do is
>   call the "**ReadProcessMemory**" function with the "**Handle**" parameter set
>   to **0xFFFFFFFF**, the "**lpBaseAddress**" parameter set to the image base,
>   and the "**nSize**" parameter set to the size of image. If it returns
>   false, then at least one memory breakpoint is present.

As for your other question -- "How can i avoid detection?" -- that is answered here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8510/1562

> You can't know how to avoid getting detected if you don't know how the
>   detection works. I'd recommend finding and reverse engineering the
>   detection logic so that you can either disable it (patch it out) or
>   better understand how to avoid detection.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK this is possible, just read your own memory and look for 0xCC bytes. However this poses a problem since several compilers insert 0xCC bytes between functions (as kind of a trap in case of memory overwrite, I guess)

[image: INT3 padding between functions shown in IDA]

So, you would have to do is to know how many of those "innocent" INT3 was there before and check for anomalies. Sounds like prone to failure, IMHO :)

SPOILER: IIRC, this was one of the anti-RE mechanisms in the last Flare Challenge.

Comment: I did not mean `Code breakpoints (INT3)` i meant Memory breakpoints.. Like changing the Page Protection attributes with VirtualProtect or other api.. to PAGE_GUARD etc